# vb.net listbox item duplicate iterate

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have listbox on the form and inside listbox populated proxy list.

also i have two Webbrowser on the form.

i want to call each proxy to each webbrowser.

for example, webbrowser2 use 1.1.1.1 and webbrowser4 use 2.2.2.2

current problem is when use For looping it use same proxy.

webbrowser2 use 1.1.1.1 and webbrowser4 use 1.1.1.1 also.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        UseProxy(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        WebBrowser2.Navigate(FlatTextBox3.Text)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1

        UseProxy(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        WebBrowser4.Navigate(FlatTextBox3.Text)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1

    Next
```

Comment: You have only two items in list box ?

Comment: inside listbox hundred of proxy loaded. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`listBox1.SelectedIndex`starts with `-1` with is nothing.

So try to set `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0` before your `for` loop

Comment: i set but it not working . it still use same proxy to two webbrowser